# Set to center the content of the table

Tags: tables, texlive

I'm new of the latex and I have a big difficulty with the table element, I'm building the table with this code

```
\begin{table}[ht]
       \centering\small
       \caption{Specifications of LTE\label{tab:table1}}
           \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
               \toprule
               Block\\
               \midrule
               Prova di lavoro (nonce)   \\
               Transazioni valide \\
               Timestamp \\
               Merkle Tree \\
               \bottomrule
       \end{tabularx}
   \end{table}
```

and I have this effect

[image]

But I want the content of the table to the center of the context, this is possible?

This is a minimal example reproducible

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{toptesi}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{paralist}{\obeyspaces\global\let =\space}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}   % this package promotes good tabular style
\usepackage{caption}    % for customising caption style
\usepackage{siunitx} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
       \centering\small
       \caption{Specifications of LTE\label{tab:table1}}
           \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
               \toprule
               Block\\
               \midrule
               Prova di lavoro (nonce)   \\
               Transazioni valide \\
               Timestamp \\
               Merkle Tree \\
               \bottomrule
       \end{tabularx}
   \end{table}

 \end{document}
```

Also, I want the caption in the bottom position, what is the correct setting?

Comment: Move the `\caption{}` just above the `\end{table}`.

Comment: Like this: `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\hfil}X}`?

Comment: Why you define two column in table but than use only one?

Comment: I'd recommend that you take a look at ou preamble and clean it up. Please do not load packages more than once.

Comment: Does one of the following examples suit your needs? https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddjz1.png

Comment: Thanks for help guys, @leandriis, yes the Tabella 3

Comment: @Zarko where I declare two columns?

Comment: with `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}` where `l` and `X` are column specifiers. In table you than use only `l`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `tabularx` if you don't want your table to be as wide as the linewith. A simple `tabular` will also do the trick:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{toptesi}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
       \centering\small
       \caption{Specifications of LTE\label{tab:table1}}
           \begin{tabular}{l}
               \toprule
               Block\\
               \midrule
               Prova di lavoro (nonce)   \\
               Transazioni valide \\
               Timestamp \\
               Merkle Tree \\
               \bottomrule
       \end{tabular}
\end{table}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank for your time, this is the solution that I searched

Answer (score 1):

This is rather extend comment. Do you like to have the following?

[image]

MWE (Minimal Working Example; a small but complete document which reproduce your problem) for above table us:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%{toptesi}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}    % for customising caption style

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
       \toprule
Block                       \\
       \midrule
Prova di lavoro (nonce)     \\
Transazioni valide          \\
Timestamp                   \\
Merkle Tree                 \\
       \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Specifications of LTE}
\label{tab:table1}
   \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note, in your preamble you load many package twice. Please clean up preamble. At this ask yourself, are you really need all these packages.

Comment: Thank for your time an thanks for your example, I work on clean the preamble

Comment: How can we reduce the dimension of the table? for reducing the width of the line